# New Force.com IDE logging changes against entire Apex code base?

Tags: apex, ide

I recently started using the new Force.com IDE plugin (in Eclipse Kepler). Since that happened, today I looked in the Setup Audit Trail log and was shocked to see that against my name there have been over 50,000 code changes in the last few days!

It appears that whenever I edit & save a single file from the IDE, somehow 100% of the code gets a "Changed XXX Apex Class code" event logged against it, even though a diff shows that nothing actually changed in the files I didn't edit. This seems impossible, since the saves only take 1-2 seconds max.

Has anybody seen this, and can anybody shed light on how to prevent it? Or if it is caused by the Force.com IDE, or possibly a Tooling API or platform bug? It's a huge annoyance and quite disturbing to my client's admin team :)

Comment: I don't see this in the IDE bug list https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues. Flagging it there would probably get it looked at whether the cause is in the IDE or not.

Comment: Very strange. I have updated to the Summer '14 version (31.0.0.201406301722) and it is defaulted to "Work Offline". So every save takes about 7-8 seconds and I need to confirm the save dialogue 2 times. Just checked the audit trail and there is nothing special.

Comment: New Force.com IDE is working fine for me. I didn't see any issue. Audit Trail is showing only those changes that i made.

Comment: @mast0r I'm using also 31.0.0.201406301722 on eclipse 4.4.0.v20140606-1558 and it saves actually in up to 3-4 secs as typically with toolingApi from Germany. @ jkraybill I also don't have the issue with the logs. --- But since a few minutes (during my tests here for this question) I can't save anymore at all. Just got the warning "File saved locally, not to server" and Type "Force.com sync state". Doesn't help to refresh not even to delete and recreate the projects... damn...

Comment: I saw this recently - after making some small changes to a handful of Apex classes it set 'LastModifiedDate' & 'LastModifiedBy' to me on every class, trigger, page & component in the org!

Comment: @DavinC It can happen if you selects the whole project or "src" folder (accidentally) and then do "Save to Server". That's why it is a good idea to set the "Link with Editor" button on (Package explorer).

Comment: @mast0r, maybe that's what happened although I usually save files individually as I work on them. I'll check out that 'Link with editor' option though, thanks.

Comment: @mast0r I am CERTAIN that this was not what I did -- I saw every file updated every few minutes while I was in the IDE, doing single saves at a time. It is remotely possible that I did that accidentally once, but not dozens of times.

Comment: Likewise @jkraybill, that's what I do too.

Comment: I think you should use mavensmate plugin in sublime text editor for your salesforce project instead of force.com plugin in eclipse .

Comment: I have seen this for years, and was never really able to come up with a reproducible scenario to cause it to happen.  I *think* it was related to when the IDE did not close gracefully...

Answer (score 1):

I had seen this before.
Eclipse Force.com IDE may deploy the whole project after it crashed and restarted.Not allways but there has this risk.I don't sure that it is IDE's bug.

I recommend you to use Sublime Text3 instead of Eclipse,it is awesome.
Reference the following page and you can easily setup it.
[Setup an awesome Salesforce developer environment with Sublime Text 3](https://goo.gl/yYRhGb)